# How to do this process?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I have documentation to do some setup on Eclipse but I do not know how to do it in Android Studio. I am unable to take step from 52 line number.

```
40 Open Eclipse and select File -> New -> Android Project
41 From the next window ("New Android Project" ) fill the text fields like this:
42
43 Project name: myFirstApp
44 Location: 
45 Build Target: Android 2.0 (at least)
46 Application name: myFirstApp
47 Package name: org.doubango.test
48 Check "Create Activity" and name it "Main"
49
50
51 Click on Finish to create the project
52 From the Eclipse package explorer, right click on myFirstApp and select "Properties" then
"Android" from the left
53
54
55 From the properties window, select "Add" button then select android-ngn-stack from the list of
the available libraries
56
57
58 Select "Java Compiler" from the left and change the version from 1.5 to 1.6
59
60
61 Select "Java Build Path" from the left, then "Libraries"
62
63
64 From "Java Build Path 1/2", select "Add JARs..." then android-ngn-stack/libs/simple-xml-
2.3.4.jar , then "OK" to close the window
65
66
67 Click on "OK" to close the window
```

Please tell me how to take these steps.

Comment: Eclipse ADT is not supported since 2015

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies
Look for "Local binary dependency" if you have only jar file

Answer (score 1):

No need for all these steps, You can start your project directly on android studio.

Then you can add dependencies in build.gradle as you need